# Is there any wa that I can publish failure history of failed test scenarios in html report with SpecFlow+SpecRun?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, specflow, specrun

Can we publish the details of failed test cases statistics in HTML report of SpecRun? 
Example: Analytics of failed test cases in previous executions.
If one test scenario is failing from the past 5 runs, In Error Details section of specrun report, 5 needs to be displayed against that test case. So that we can analyse whether this test case failure is new in current run or its there from previous builds.

Can we make any settings to run only failed test cases in the previous run with SpecFlow+SpenRun ?

Comment: Hi @Anusha How was it going with this case? Display the historical failed tests in the same page is not impossible, unless you find a way to merge the past test results files together and publish it to azure devops server.

Answer (score 0):

To publish historical failed tests and displayed them against that test case and run only failed test cases might not be achieveable in azure devops.

However you can achieve rerun failed test cases via **visual studio test** task.  You can configure the threshold to rerun failed tests and the maximum attempts under **Execution options** in **visual studio test** task.
[image]

Comment: Many.. Thanks for this.